# Best Method to find a single frequency within uncompressed PCM

Tags: audio, frequency, pcm

FFT deals with multiple frequencies. I would like to know what algorithm is best to find only a single given frequency within a single channel of pcm raw data. A block diagram of the process or flow would be preferred method since I use BASIC or FORTRAN and not C or C++.

Comment: Hi! What research have you done already? What do you mean by "single frequency"? Dominant frequency?

Answer (score 0):

when you populate an array with your raw audio ( PCM ) sample values in floating point then call FFT it results in a new array of complex numbers ( `complex_fft` ) ... each element of this new array `complex_fft`  represents the next frequency bin ... just calculate the magnitude of the complex number stored on the closest frequency bin to your chosen single frequency ... or interpolate between two adjacent freq bins if your desired frequency lies in between these freqs

here is the general approach to parsing your `complex_fft`

```
incr_freq := sample_rate / number_of_samples  //  with sample_rate of 44100 samples per second, and one second worth of samples ( 44100 )
                                              //  this gives you a frequency increment resolution of 1 Hertz ... IE each freq bin is 1 Hertz apart

nyquist_limit_index := int(number_of_samples / 2)

for index_fft, curr_complex := range complex_fft { // we really only use half this range + 1

    if index_fft <= nyquist_limit_index && curr_freq >= min_freq && curr_freq < max_freq {

        curr_real = real(curr_complex) // pluck out real portion of imaginary number
        curr_imag = imag(curr_complex) // ditto for im

        curr_mag = 2.0 * math.Sqrt(curr_real*curr_real+curr_imag*curr_imag) / number_of_samples

        curr_theta = math.Atan2(curr_imag, curr_real)

        curr_dftt := discrete_fft{

            real:      2.0 * curr_real,
            imaginary: 2.0 * curr_imag,
            magnitude: curr_mag,
            theta:     curr_theta,
        }

        *all_dft = append(*all_dft, curr_dftt)

        all_magnitudes = append(all_magnitudes, curr_mag)
    }
    curr_freq += incr_freq
}
```