# How would I break down a signals sound pressure level by frequency

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I've been given some digitized sound recordings and asked to plot the sound pressure level per Hz.

The signal is sampled at 40KHz and the units for the y axis are simply volts.

I've been asked to produce a graph of the SPL as dB/Hz vs Hz.

EDIT: The input units are voltage vs time.

Does this make sense?  I though SPL was a time domain measure?

If it does make sense how would I go about producing this graph?  Apply the dB formula (20 * log10(x) IIRC) and do an FFT on that or...?

Comment: any signal which wobbles up and down can be considered a time series ... simply feed an array of points on that curve into a FFT call which will return back a new array of complex numbers ... iterate across this complex array ... array element 0 is zero frequency ... next array element is separated by incr_freq which is defined by `incr_freq := sample_rate / number_of_samples`  ... for details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69271957/147175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a [Power Spectral Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density). Matlab, for example, has a [pwelch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) function that does *literally* what you're asking for. To scale to dBSPL/Hz, simply apply `10*log10([psd])` where `psd` is the output of `pwelch`. Let me know if you need help with the function inputs.

If you're working with a different framework, let me know which, 100% sure they'll have a version of this function, possibly with a different output format in which case the scaling might be different.

Comment: Great, thx!  A few questions 1. Why Welsh specifically and not an FFT 2. I've seen the formula you cited above a 20*log10() instead, what's up with that?  And for the record I'm using numpy/scypi.

Comment: The `pwelch` method reduces the variance of your PSD estimate by computing an FFT squared magnitude (or *periodogram*) at subsequent overlapped time windows and averaging them. By doing that it reduces the de-correlated components while accentuating the correlated ones. If you don't know about the method, read [Welch's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method).
You can use an FFT, sure, but not only will you get a biased estimate, you'll also  have to do the [scaling](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/32205/63763) yourself.

Comment: As far 10 or 20log10, that's just the definition of a decibel: 10log10(P2/P1) where P1 and P2 are powers, just like a *Power Spectral Density*.
20log10(V2/V1) would be the definition for a ratio of *voltages*

Comment: This sounds like the right approach then.  FYI the input units from the mic are volts vs time.  Another question I have is whether I should somehow take into account the freq response curve of the mic itself.

Comment: it's 10log10 because of the "squared" in my previous comment.
If you need to do some calibration then yes you could use the mic response.

Comment: For the record I went with this python code. ```    data = y_axis_data['Sound'].to_numpy()

    freq, psd = scipy.signal.welch(data, fs=40e3)

    pyplot.figure()
    pyplot.plot(freq, 10 * numpy.log10(psd) )
    pyplot.xlabel('freq (Hz)')
    pyplot.ylabel('dB/Hz')``` Does that look reasonable?

Comment: yep! Pretty sure scipy.welch defaults the frame size to NONE, so you'd want to play around with the nperseg and noverlap arguments, depending on the frequency resolution dF you'd like (nperseg = fs/dF) and you can keep overlap at half of nperseg but otherwise that's it ;)

Comment: Ok the graph is looking fine, except the y-scale runs from -95dB to -50.  I'm guessing that to covert to positive numbers I'd just have to subtract my values from some threshold value.